# Is there a vue-jest config that allows jest to coverage .vue SFC with no methods?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxtjs on a project and testing with jest. Recently I found out that vue-jest do not coverage SFC without methods (JS methods). I would like to know if there is any config I can set up that alows jest to watch those files.

Comment: If there are no methods, there's nothing to cover. Why would you want to list the files anyway?

Comment: I'd like to test some of the rendering features. Like testig if the props passed are rendered or if the slots are working correctly. Aren't these testable features?

Comment: Yes, you can test props and slots, but how is that related to the code coverage in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I migth be missing something. The coverage report is only related to Javascript function? It doesnt cover other features, like these templates ones?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you want the coverage report to show code coverage for your templates (e.g., slots and props). I don't think that's possible because the templates aren't JavaScript.

Comment: Hummm.. okay, that is helpfull. Usualy what do you test on vue components ? would it be only the methods, and stuff with javascript?

Comment: The templates could still be tested effectively. Use Vue Test Utils `propsData` mounting option, and check for the expected result, e.g. in `wrapper.html()` or in Jest snapshots.

Comment: Got it. It wont appear on the coverage report though right? I'm going test it anyway hahah. Thanks man!